# Python code to connect azure blob storage via azure automation runbook

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am new to python and trying to connect azure blob storage via azure automation runbook using below code.But the code fails with below error . I am using python 3 runbook and have all the required modules imported and python package added for azure blob and azure core.
Any help for the same will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

**Error :**
[image]

Code

```
from azure.storage import *
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service = BlobServiceClient(account_name='<added blob storage name>', account_key='<added blob storage key>')
blobs = []
marker = None
while True:
batch = blob_service_client.list_blobs('data', marker=marker)
blobs.extend(batch)
if not batch.next_marker:
break
marker = batch.next_marker
for blob in blobs:
print(blob.name)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which package you use?

Comment: I have used azure_core-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl package. Additionally I have imported azure.storage and azure modules

Comment: Could you please tell me the package version you use?

Comment: Azure core : 1.12.0 , Azure.storage : 4.6.1, Azure : 1.0.3. Is there any sequence which needs to followed while importing this package and modules in azure runbook ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage Azure blob with python3 in Azure runbook, we need to import package `azure.storage.blob` with its dependencies.

For example

1. Manual Download packages

```
pip3 download -d <output dir name> azure-storage-blob==12.8.0
```

2.Import these packages
[image]

3.Runbook

a.code

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connect_str = ''
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client('test')
blobs = container_client.list_blobs( )
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

b.test
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do we just need to upload the whl file as shown in screenshot, i a uskng python 3.8 version and getting error.

Comment: Is it a question but an answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34431747)